# How to get a unique plot when using matplolib gca()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a program to add text labels above dots in a matplolib's 3d animation.

However when I use gca() to work on my label's axis (ax); I end up with two figures when calling plt.show().

[two figures instead of one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE6BP.jpg)

---The program starts here---

````
import numpy as np

from PyAstronomy import pyasl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.animation as animation

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

satellites_values = [[1.0, 2.0, 0.50, 0.0, 30.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.20, 0.0, 90.0, 0.0], [10.0, 2.0, 0.39, 0.0, 180.0, 0.0]]

satellites_pos = []

red_dots_pos = []

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

anim = []


def update(i, pos, red_dot, annotation):
    red_dot.set_data([pos[i][1], pos[i][0]])
    red_dot.set_3d_properties(pos[i][2])

    x2, y2, _ = proj3d.proj_transform(pos[i][1], pos[i][0], pos[i][2], ax.get_proj())
    annotation.set_position((x2,y2))    
    return red_dot, annotation

def create_system(satellites_list):
    for satellite in satellites_list:

        t = np.linspace(0, 4, 200)
        orbit = pyasl.KeplerEllipse(a=satellite[0], per=satellite[1], e=satellite[2], Omega=satellite[3], i=satellite[4], w=satellite[5])
        pos = orbit.xyzPos(t)

        red_dot, = ax .plot(pos[::, 1], pos[::, 0], pos[::, 2], 'ro')

        text = 'aaa' 
        annotation = ax.text2D(pos[::, 1],pos[::, 0], text)
        
        anim.append(animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, 200, fargs=(pos, red_dot, annotation), interval=100, blit=False))        
        ax.plot(pos[::, 1], pos[::, 0], pos[::, 2], 'k-') 


create_system(satellites_values)
ax.plot([0], [0], [0], 'bo', markersize=20, label="Earth")


# Hide grid lines
ax.grid(False)

# Hide axes ticks
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])

plt.style.use('default')
plt.legend()
plt.show() ```
````

When I try:

```
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
```

or

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

I want to have a unique figure because this program is part of a GUI that's supposed to show the dots with their label.
I was wondering if anyone here knew how to fix this.

Comment: WHERE do you get that error?  Which line, exactly?  You are calling `plt.figure()` twice.  You probably want to delete the first call (`fig = plt.figure()`).

Comment: If you do `ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')` you create again a new figure (because you called `plt.figure()` a second time).  You could do `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`, which should work without problems. The error message you mention might come from the line `annotation = ax.text2D(pos[::, 1], pos[::, 0], text)` where `pos[::,1]` is an array of values, while you only should give one specific value.  E.g.`annotation = ax.text2D(pos[0, 1], pos[0, 0], text)`. Note that when you get an error, the complete trace is important. You might want to run in debug-mode to find errors.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC! I just replaced `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')`  with a for loop which takes into account every "subdatasets" like so:  `for a in range(len(pos[1])):
    annotation = ax.text2D(pos[a, 1], pos[a, 0], text, zorder=1, color='k')`. Now it is working exactly how I want it to, using ax as a subplot.